# What type of import statement gets used for a file transpiled from ES6 to ES5?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I have an index.js file that was successfully importing a class-based file using E2015, like so:

```
import { Handler } from './Library/Transform/Handler.js';
```

But because of compatibility issues I now have to transpile that file down to ES5, but then I started getting this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './Library/Transform/Handler.js' does not provide an export named 'Handler'.
```

Okay fair enough, but I am not sure how to import this then, I have tried just a broken AMD like so: `require('./Library/Transform/Handler.js');`, but I get the exact same error.

I have found similar questions on here, but none that address this issue specifically.

Then I look at the actual transpiled file and at the end of the file I do see:

```
exports.Handler = Handler;

return exports;

}({}));
```

So it is exporting `Handler` and I have also tried:

```
var Handler = require('./Library/Transform/Handler.js');
```

and I continue to get the same error.

Below is the `rollup.config.js` file:

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import { uglify } from "rollup-plugin-uglify";
import banner from "rollup-plugin-banner";

var git = require("git-rev-sync");
var buildVer = process.env.BUILD || 0;
var currRevision = git.long();

export default {
  input: ["./src/Handler.js"],
  output: [
    {
      file: "./dist/Handler.js",
      format: "iife",
      name: "version",
    },
    {
      file: "./dist/Handler.min.js",
      format: "iife",
      name: "version",
      plugins: [uglify()],
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    banner(
      "\t<%= pkg.name %>\n\t<%= pkg.version %>-" +
      buildVer +
      "\n\t" +
      currRevision +
      "\n\t" +
      new Date().toString() + 
      "\n\t<%= pkg.description%>"
    ),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
     extensions: [".js"],
     exclude: ["node_modules"],
     presets: [
       [
         "@babel/preset-env",
         {
           targets: "ie 11",
           modules: false,
           useBuiltIns: "usage",
           corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
         }
       ]
     ]
    })
  ]
};
```

The untranspiled `Handler.js` file import statements has some partials that we use to make our workflow easier when developing out these forms, it looks like so:

```
import { XHandler } from './xy/js-es6/x-es6.js';
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
import getHelp from './_Partials/getHelp.11ty.js';
import pwd from './_Partials/pwd.11ty.';
import challengeMe from './_Partials/challengeMe.11ty';
import lockedOut from './_Partials/lockedOut.11ty';
import infoSec from './_Partials/infoSec.11ty';
import lockedOutAgain from './_Partials/lockedOutAgain.11ty';

const debug = false;

export class Handler extends XHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('Handler:Constructor');
  }

  createFormSession(formId, payload) {
    console.log('Handler:createFormSession');

    return new FormSession(formId, payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to `import * as Handler from ...` where you may need to do `Handler.Handler` to extract it. Is this with a current version of something like Babel?

Comment: @tadman, no no Babel involved. I am using **rollupJS**

Comment: I've had issues writing NPM modules that behave with Node in ESM and the browser with ES6 along these lines.

Comment: Add your rollup config. Almost certainly where the issue is.

Comment: @tadman, I tried `import * as Handler from ...` and still getting the same error.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. `import *` doesn't care about names.

Comment: @tadman, I added the `rollup.config.js` file.

Comment: What if you get rid of the `.js` at the end - `import { Handler } from './Library/Transform/Handler`

Comment: @Adam, same issue even without the `.js` extension.

Comment: @Daniel - well post the code (raw - untranspiled) of `./Library/Transform/Handler` - just the export lines, we don't need to see the full contents.

Comment: @Adam, added the export lines, its a class-based file.

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't look like you're importing the file you think you are. I copied your rollup config and created a trivial reproduction case, and the only way I could your error message is if the file didn't export `Handler` - verify (triple check) that you're importing what you think you are - the file is supposed to be at `src/Library/Transform/Handler.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221242/discussion-between-daniel-and-adam).

Comment: @tadman, your answer is the correct one. It was not working because it was a caching issue, refreshing was not enough I had to go in the browser and clear cache.

Comment: I thought something strange was going on.